# The transaction log for database is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-insert, bulkupdate

We are doing a delete from a few tables in one database (say FirstDB), and will insert about 93,357 rows (one row at a time ) into one Log table in another database (say SecondDB).

The databases Recovery Model is Full.

Each row contains 6 columns of data

```
[DeleteTime] [datetime] NULL,
[FilePath] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[DocumentID] [int] NULL,
[AnotherCol] [varchar](50) NULL,
[AnotherCol2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[AnotherCol3] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

On previous insert, when we inserted 153,000 rows, we got the error "The transaction log for database 'SecondDB' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'

What is the best way to avoid using a lot of space in the transaction log ?

Shall I commit transaction for say every 1000 insertion to the database SecondDB ?

This is the code to delete from FirstDb and insert into SecondDB

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spGetDocuments", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                foreach (DataRow aRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Code to insert into FirstDB

                        //Code to insert into SecondDB
                        cmdSecondDB = new SqlCommand("spUpdateDeleteDocsLog", con);
                        cmdSecondDB.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmdSecondDB.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FilePath", sDocumentPath));
                        cmdSecondDB.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DocumentID", aRow["DocumentID"]));
                        :
                        iRow = cmdSecondDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmdSecondDB.Dispose();
                        cmdSecondDB = null;
                    }
                }
                ds.Dispose();
                ds = null;
                da.Dispose();
                da = null;
                con.Close();
            }               
        }
```

Also, is there a way to calculate how much transaction log will be taken by 93,357 rows of the above 6 rows of data ?

Thank you

Comment: You're holding the transaction open too long, so yeah you need to batch it. But use `SqlBulkCopy` with `SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock`, it's much faster. And set your parameter types and sizes `Parameters.Add("FilePath", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = sDocumentPath` or for bulk copy set the column type and size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The databases Recovery Model is Full.

Then the only thing that matters is the size of your log file and the frequency of your log backups.  Batching doesn't cause less log to be written or allow the log space to be reused before the next transaction log backup under the [Full Recovery Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, David. Transaction Log Backup is every 30 minutes at the top of the hour and every 30 minutes after the hour, for ex at 7 AM, 7:30 AM, 8 AM, 8:30 AM, etc. The size of the Transaction Log was increased to 500 MB, with Autogrowth by 256 MB, Limited to 2,097,152 MB. Do you think we will hit Transaction Full with insertion of 93,357 records of the above 6 columns ?

Comment: Is it a good idea to shrink the transaction log file before we start the process ? And, do you suggest we start the process close to the time the Transaction Log is backed up, for ex closed to 7 AM, so that the Transaction log will be backed up (and truncated) while the process is going on.

Comment: You should never shrink the transaction log, and just make it big enough to hold all the log records generated during your busiest hour.